# Understanding a complex set description

Tags: intuition, puzzle

I am trying to understand the following math expression, describing the possible sets of a [15 Puzzle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle):

[image: Puzzle 15 sets]

The expressions for `tile` and `position` are straight forward, I am having a difficulty "translating" the `board` expression to plain English. 
Here is what I understand:

Board is a set of a combination of all positions `C` and `error`. `C` is defined as the set of all combinations positions and  with all tiles. `C`  is always 16 (restriction given by `|`). 
And (`^`) for all `c` (a combination), which is defined by `p` (position) and `t` which are subset of `C` we must also have: All `c'`, defined by `p'` and `t'` there is the requirement that `c'` is different then `c` and hence `p'` and `p` are not equal and also `t'` and `t` are not equal. Meaning each tile can be on a single location of each combination.

This is horribly complicated in English, compared to math. However, I am not sure I understand it correctly, and I would be happy to hear if I am wrong or right, and how the above expression can be interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's get through this step by step: The set $(\mathrm{position}\setminus\mathrm{error})\times\mathrm{tile}$ is the set of all tuples $(p,t)$ for which $p$ is a position, and $t$ is a tile. Such a tuple just says that the tile $t$ is currently at position $p$.

A set $C$ is just a subset of $(\mathrm{position}\setminus\mathrm{error})\times\mathrm{tile}$ with certain restrictions. First of all, it has to have exactly 16 elements. Secondly, if we take to elements $c$, $c'$ of $C$, which are different to each other we want them to differ in both coordinates. So if we have two different positions, we want to associate two different tiles. And vice versa, given two different tiles, they have to be at two different positions.

The set $\mathrm{board}$ is now the union of the set of all $C$ that satisfy theses conditions, i.e. the set of all *valid* boards, with the single-element set $\{\mathrm{error}\}$. So $\mathrm{board}$ contains all valid board positions and a single board position  $\mathrm{error}$ to denote non-valid boards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer roman! You made it much less cumbersome than I did.